# Django Form: form with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm making online shopping mall using `Django`(1.9.7) framework.

I think that showing codes is much easier than explaining in text.

**models.py**

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Variation(TimeStampedModel):
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('black', '흑백'),
        ('single', '단색'),
        ('multi', '컬러'),
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=0,
        max_digits=15,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    color = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=COLOR_CHOICES,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('product', 'color'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product) + ' - ' + self.get_color_display()
```

I create form in my `product_detail` view and pass it as context data to `template`.

**views.py**

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = "product"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        product = self.get_object()
        context['cartitem_form'] = CartItemForm(product)

        return context
```

What I want to do through form:

> > I want to show `variations` only related with given `product`. So I pass `product` as argument of `form` in `view` and save this `product`. And I'm trying to set the `variation` queryset through `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class CartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    variation = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Variation.objects.filter(product=self.product)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = (
            'variation',
            'width',
            'height',
            'quantity',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.product = kwargs.pop('product')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        cart_item = super().save(commit=False)
        cart_item.save()

        return cart_item
```

but it doesn't work. How can I implement this?

Comment: You will have to do that in `__init__` not in field definition. There are already many posts here regarding this. search sub-category or linked fields.